# Go float number division

Tags: go

I try to get 2.4/0.8 == 3 in Go

```
w:=float64(2.4)
fmt.Println(math.Floor(w/0.8),math.Floor(2.4/0.8) )
```

It gives me "2 3".

The question is why `math.Floor(w/0.8)` won't give me 3. Is it the precision limit of float number?

Comment: well, I have to nudge it to give me 3, so I did:  `const NUDGE = 1e-10` and `math.Floor(w/0.8 + NUDGE)`

Answer (score 9):

The program output is correct. The representation of many real numbers in the IEEE format is not precise. The first number is actually (in the limited 64 bits version of it) less than 3 so floor returns '2' correctly. The second one is computed at compile time using greater precision.

Recomended [reading](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is the precision limit. float64 is pretty precise, but 2.4 can't be stored exactly in binary. When both the numbers are constants, the computation is done in higher precision at compile time, and when the result is rounded to float64, it comes out to exactly 3. But when one of the numbers is a variable, the calculation has to be done at runtime, and it comes out to 2.9999999999999996, which Floor truncates to 2.

Answer (score -1):

Although this doesn't answer the question(why) I've found this page looking for a round function so just in case someone finds it helpful here is my own solution:

```
   func Round(val float64) (float64) {
        if float64(int(val)) < val {
            return float64(int(val) + 1)
        }
        return val
    }
```

Comment: This is not a Round function. It's not even a correct ceiling function. Use the math library.

Comment: it was a correct ceiling function for my case. I needed to round x.x to x+1 so here is the function. The math library didn't provide a such function. I already checked it.

Comment: Then don't call it Round if it's a Ceiling function. this doesn't handle negatives, Inf or NaN. also [math.Ceil](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Ceil).